# How to add wow.js/animate.css on Shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, animate.css, wow.js

I am in the process of creating a Shopify store and would like to go a little beyond what the themes are offering. Specifically I am triyng to add [wow.js](https://wowjs.uk/docs.html) and [animate.css](https://animate.style/).

As you can see below, I have added the CDN for Animate.css in the `head` tag of `template.liquid`.

[image]

Next I added the CND for Wow.js and activated is as such:

[image]

It seems to be loading the scripts just fine, even adds the `animated` class as one scrolls to the element, but for some reason none of the aniamtion is taking place.

[image]

Any input into alleviating this issue is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well this was utterly annoying. Anyhow the way to refernce/activate Animation.css animations now seems to be with class `animate__animated` and NOT just `animated` like it used to be.

This means that when one is initialising wow.js one must change that `animationClass` to `animate__animated` as such:

```js
new WOW({
  animateClass: 'animate__animated', // --> WOW default is animated but that does not work anymore
  }).init();
```

And the Animation.css animations must be as such:

```html
<div class="wow animate__fadeInUp">Lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your theme's CSS is overriding **animate.min.css** since it's being loaded before it. Try loading **animate.min.css** last, just before the closing `</head>` tag